Fetching authorization rules PDA for a pNFT
I'm using Metaplex's Umi library to work with pNFTs via a custom program that I built, and one of the required accounts for most instructions is the Authorization Rules (& auth rules program). Theoretically, the instructions will work if I upgrade the program to omit these accounts, but then the program will lack coverage for many collections.
How can I fetch the authorization rules account for a given pNFT?

You can access the authentication rules for a given pNFT by inspecting the token's metadata account. This can be done with umi, and mpl-token-metadata. Fetching the PDA and it's data will look something like this:
const nftMetadata = findMetadataPda(umi, { mint: publicKey(nftMint) });

const metadataInfo = await fetchMetadata(umi, publicKey(nftMetadata));

The 'metadataInfo' object will include a 'programmableConfig' field, which will contain the ruleSet account. You can access it with the following:
//@ts-ignore
const ruleSet = metadataInfo.programmableConfig.value.ruleSet.value;

Typescript doesn't like this because it uses an Option type (sometimes pNFTs won't have rulesets associated with them), hence the ts-ignore. Not perfect, but works in my case :)
